# C# - Problemas ao ler dados de um XML retornado de um site

Tags: c#, xml

Quero pegar o Localização de um IP externo e para isso utilizei um site em que simplesmente coloco o IP que desejo e ele retorna o XML com as informações.

Exemplo:

```
freegeoip.net/xml/4.2.2.2
```

ou seja:

```
freegeoip.net/[tipo]/[ip]
```

Para isso estou pegando todos os caracteres desse site e tentando trabalhar com uma string contendo um XML dentro e retornando o que eu quero:

```
public static string getLocationIPAddress()
{
        string country = null;
        string state = null;
        string city = null;

        System.Net.WebClient t = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string site = t.DownloadString("https://freegeoip.net/xml/" 
                                              + getExternIPAdrress());          

        XElement xml = XElement.Parse(site);           

        country = xml.Attribute("CountryName").Value;
        state = xml.Attribute("RegionName").Value;
        city = xml.Attribute("City").Value;   

        return "País: " + country + "Estado: " + state + "Cidade: " + city;

}
```

Já tentei tirar os `\n\t` que aparecem na string site, já tentei trabalhar com outras funções da `XElement` e também já procurei por outras classes porém a maioria trabalha com arquivo e não com string.

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: Ele gera uma Exception em:
country = xml.Attribute("CountryName").Value;
e dai não passa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O retorno em [`XML`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) talvez não seja o melhor, mas, tem uma maneira:

***Exemplo do retorno:***

```
<Response>
    <IP>8.8.8.8</IP>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
    <RegionCode>CA</RegionCode>
    <RegionName>California</RegionName>
    <City>Mountain View</City>
    <ZipCode>94035</ZipCode>
    <TimeZone>America/Los_Angeles</TimeZone>
    <Latitude>37.386</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-122.0838</Longitude>
    <MetroCode>807</MetroCode>
</Response>
```

***Utilize*** [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static string getLocationIPAddress()
{             
    System.Net.WebClient t = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string site = t.DownloadString("https://freegeoip.net/xml/" 
                                               + getExternIPAdrress());


    var xml = (from d in XDocument.Parse(site).Descendants("Response")
               let ip = d.Element("IP")
               let countryCode = d.Element("CountryCode")
               let countryName = d.Element("CountryName")
               let regionCode = d.Element("RegionCode")
               let regionName = d.Element("RegionName")
               let city = d.Element("City")
               let zipCode = d.Element("ZipCode")
               let timeZone = d.Element("TimeZone")
               let latitude = d.Element("Latitude")
               let longitude = d.Element("Longitude")
               let metroCode = d.Element("MetroCode")
               select new
               {
                   IP = ip.Value,
                   CountryCode = countryCode.Value,
                   CountryName = countryName.Value,
                   RegionCode = regionCode.Value,
                   RegionName = regionName.Value,
                   City = city.Value,
                   ZipCode = zipCode.Value,
                   TimeZone = timeZone.Value,
                   Latitude = latitude.Value,
                   Longitude = longitude.Value,
                   MetroCode = metroCode.Value

               })
              .FirstOrDefault();



    return "País: " 
            + xml.CountryName + "Estado: " 
            + xml.RegionName + "Cidade: " 
            + xml.City;    
}
```

Comment: Seu método funcionou perfeitamente! Só esta errado no retorno dele, em que você CountryCode em vez de RegionName para o Estado. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Sou novo aqui, onde clico aqui para dizer que a sua resposta foi a correta?

Comment: E por curiosidade, qual séria o melhor retorno para se trabalhar?

Comment: @Amzero O melhor retorno seria `json`, estou alterando a resposta pelo detalhe sinalizado e para marcar como correto abaixo da seta que aponta pra baixo tem um check é só clicar em cima.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o XDocument você consegue fazer seu parser da seguinte maneira:

```
public static string getLocationIPAddress()
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var xmlResponse = client.DownloadString("https://freegeoip.net/xml/4.2.2.2");
        var parsedDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponse);

        var rootElements = from items 
            in parsedDocument.Descendants("Response")
            select items;

        var countryName = rootElements.Descendants("CountryName").FirstOrDefault();
        var regionName = rootElements.Descendants("RegionName").FirstOrDefault();
        var cityName = rootElements.Descendants("City").FirstOrDefault();

        if (countryName != null && regionName != null && cityName != null)
            result = $"País: {countryName.Value}; Estado: {regionName.Value}; Cidade: {cityName.Value};";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Fiz algumas modificações em seu métodos mas retorna o resultado esperado.

Você também pode pesquisar um pouco mais sobre o XDocument e como utilizá-lo neste link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Seu método funcionou perfeitamente! obrigado pela ajuda. vou dar uma conferida no link.